# Slide show image not displaying

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hi i have an issue with the preview images in my slide show:

html:

```
 <ul runat="server" id="MyShel" class="pslides">

 </ul>
```

aspx.cs:

```
        DataTable objdt = new DataTable();
        string query = "select * from SixtyDayImages where UserId='" + UserId + "';";
        SqlDataAdapter objda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, objcon);
        objcon.Open();
        objda.Fill(objdt);
        objcon.Close();
        StringBuilder objstring = new StringBuilder();
        if (objdt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < objdt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                objstring.Append("<li><img src=\"" + objdt.Rows[i]       
            ["ImageUrl"].ToString() + "\" width=\"400\" height=\"600\" /></li>");
            }
            MyShel.InnerHtml = objstring.ToString();
        }
```

image path is along the lines of `"~\SixtyDayImage\image.jpg"`

below is a snap shot where showing the desired result. i want to bind all the image paths from db, as above.

[image]

For some reason, my image urls are currently not working. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your page, are your image urls rendering with the tilde (~) in them? Those tilde tags only generate a relative path on the server, not on the client side. If they are coming out of db like that, try replacing the line where you generate the image URL with:

```
        objstring.Append("<li><img src=\"" + objdt.Rows[i]       
        ["ImageUrl"].Replace("~","").ToString() + "\" width=\"400\" height=\"600\" /></li>");
```

this will strip the tilde, but you will need to make sure that the resulting path is correct relative to your site root.